# NFS across vlans

Tags: nfs, vlan

I am trying to mount an NFS share from a known good NFS server across separate vlans.  The nfs server resides in the vlan 105 and the client is in vlan 202.  I can ping, ssh, telnet to port 2049. traceroute to the server does work but has the !X return code.

```
[root@wsr8js ~]# traceroute -p 2049 10.137.105.3
traceroute to 10.137.105.3 (10.137.105.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.137.202.1)  0.164 ms  51.500 ms  51.502 ms
 2  nfs01-r8.v13.forge (10.137.105.3)  0.739 ms !X  0.724 ms !X  0.745 ms !X

[root@nfs01-r8 ~]# exportfs
/viz-share      10.137.0.0/16

mount -vvvv -t nfs 10.137.105.3:/viz-share /data/viz-share just hangs for 2-3 minutes and then returns the following:

[root@wsr8js ~]# mount -vvvv -t nfs 10.137.105.3:/viz-share /data/viz-share/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Dec 28 08:47:16 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=10.137.105.3,clientaddr=10.137.202.122'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

From the client: `rpcinfo -p 10.137.105.3` hangs and produces:

```
[root@wsr8js ~]# rpcinfo -p 10.137.105.3
10.137.105.3: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
```

From the server:

```
[root@nfs01-r8 ~]# rpcinfo -p localhost
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  54095  status
    100024    1   tcp  33537  status
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  52601  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  52601  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  52601  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  43875  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  43875  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  43875  nlockmgr
```

I have disabled the firewall on both the server and client with no change.

The network is divided into separate vlans hosted by level 2 switching.

Using tcpdump on the server, I am not seeing the rpc traffic reaching the server while on the client, I see:

```
917 12.904205299    10.137.202.122  10.137.105.3    TCP 74  981 → 111 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=26880 Len=0 MSS=8960 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2986187948 TSecr=0 WS=128
928 13.948479395    10.137.202.122  10.137.105.3    TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 981 → 111 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=26880 Len=0 MSS=8960 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2986188993 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

And then repeated retransmissions at 4 seconds, 8 seconds and so on.

I am pretty sure it is network related but I am not a network engineer.

Comment: How is the router configured? Does it have any kind of firewall? The fact that RPC times out indicates some kind of firewall.

Comment: The default gateway is also the firewall.  According to my network guy there are no rules to block the traffic.  He is seeing traffic and all the packets are allow.

Comment: Well, something makes rpcinfo time out. Are you *certain* that port 111 is allowed?

Comment: !X means "communication administratively prohibited" Seems the server's outgoing traffic isn't getting to the client; if you ssh to the server, can you ping / connect back to the client?  What network settings does the server have ("route -n" output)

Comment: ping has always worked in both directions and here is the output of route -n from the server:[root@nfs01-r8 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.137.105.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
10.137.105.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
[root@nfs01-r8 ~]# ping 10.137.202.122
PING 10.137.202.122 (10.137.202.122) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.137.202.122: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.395 ms

Comment: Network guy assures me port 111 is allowed both ways.

Comment: MSS=8960 -> mtu problem? Just keep the mtu 1500 everywhere unless you have a GOOD reason not to.

Comment: More details or weirdness:  
traceroute --mtu works from client to server but not from server to client unless I set mtu to 1500 on server.  Mount still hangs as does rpcinfo -r server